# SQL Split column based on 1 or more possible delimiter and insert in new table

Tags: sql, ms-access, split, ms-access-2010

I m currently working on a SQl in MS-Access 2010 that can split a column based on a delimiter(,). In the column where I want to split on can have zero, one, two or three delimiter. I found out how i can split the column if there is only one delimiter (see SQL at the end of the question) but not if there are multiple delimiters.

The SQL is based on the following table. This table is filled with possible data that can occur in the table.

```
ID         column_value
---------------------
1          2, 44
2          1
3          8, 9, 4
4          7
```

I want to split the column "value" in a way that i create a new table like this. It is not a problem that the column "ID" is the same because this will not be the PK.

```
ID         value
---------------------
1          2
1          44
2          1
3          8
3          9
3          4
4          7
```

I tried to alter the SQL from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797377/split-delimited-entries-into-new-rows-in-access) but it only works when there is only 1 delimiter(,) due to the fact is uses the function LEFT and MID. I cant find how to alter it in a way that i can split if there are more then 1 delimiter in the column. The SQL i used to split if there is one delimiter:

```
  select * into importeddata
from (SELECT column_value, id
  FROM SourceData
  WHERE InStr(column_value, ',') = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Left(column_value, InStr(column_value, ',') - 1), id
  FROM SourceData
  WHERE InStr(column_value, ',') > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mid(column_value, InStr(column_value, ',')+1 ), id
  FROM SourceData
  WHERE InStr(column_value, ',') > 0) AS CleanedUp;
```

Does somebody knows how to split a column if there is more then one delimiter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split delimited entries into new rows in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797377/split-delimited-entries-into-new-rows-in-access)

Comment: @Valerica In that question his columns has zero or one delimiter. I m looking for a SQL that can do more then 1 delimiter. It is simular but not the same

Comment: Do you have a list of the values in the column?

Comment: @Valerica If he already tried the solution from that question, and needs further help, it's not helpful to mark as a duplicate

Comment: @GordonLinoff if you by list mean like a csv file (or something simular), I m afraid i  dont have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split and obtain a specific value, I prefer to use a user-defined function.

```vb
Public Function SplitString(str As String, delimiter As String, count As Integer) As String
    Dim strArr() As String
    strArr = Split(str, delimiter, count + 1)
    count = count - 1 'zero-based
    If UBound(strArr) >= count Then
        SplitString = strArr(count)
    End If
End Function
```

After this, you can adjust your SQL to the following:

```
SELECT * INTO importeddata
FROM (
SELECT SplitString(column_value, ',', 1), id
FROM SourceData
WHERE SplitString(column_value, ',', 1) <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT SplitString(column_value, ',', 2), id
FROM SourceData
WHERE SplitString(column_value, ',', 2) <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT SplitString(column_value, ',', 3), id
FROM SourceData
WHERE SplitString(column_value, ',', 3) <> ''
) AS A
```

If you really want an all-SQL solution, let me demonstrate to you how this can be achieved, and why this is a bad plan.

For this example, I've written the following code to automatically generate the appropriate SQL expression

```
Public Sub GenerateSQLSplit(str As String, Delimiter As String, Count As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Count = 1 Then
        Debug.Print "IIf(InStr(1, " & str & ", " & Delimiter & ") = -1, " & str & ", Left(" & str & ", InStr(1, " & str & ", " & Delimiter & ") - 1))"
    Else
        Dim strPrevious As String
        Dim strNext As String
        strPrevious = "InStr(1, " & str & "," & Delimiter & ")"
        i = Count - 1
        Do While i <> 1
            strPrevious = "InStr(" & strPrevious & " + Len(" & Delimiter & "), " & str & "," & Delimiter & ")"
            i = i - 1
        Loop
        strNext = "InStr(" & strPrevious & " + Len(" & Delimiter & "), " & str & " , " & Delimiter & ")"
        Debug.Print "IIf( " & strPrevious & "> 0, IIf(" & strNext & " < 1, Mid(" & str & ", " & strPrevious & " + Len(" & Delimiter & ")), Mid(" & str & ", " & strPrevious & " + Len(" & Delimiter & "), " & strNext & " - " & strPrevious & " - Len(" & Delimiter & "))), """") "
    End If
End Sub
```

Let's use the example to generate a simple split: I want the 6th element of the following string: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

To generate the string, in the immediate window:

```
GenerateSQLSplit "'1,2,3,4,5,6,7'", "','", 6
```

Results in the following expression to return the 6th element of that string (SQL only):

```
IIf( InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',')> 0, IIf(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' , ',') < 1, Mid('1,2,3,4,5,6,7', InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(',')), Mid('1,2,3,4,5,6,7', InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
,',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' , ',') - InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(InStr(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') + Len(','), '1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',') - Len(','))), "")
```

Append `SELECT` to the start of that, and execute it as a query, and it returns `6`, as expected. Only you have a totally horrid query, while with the UDF you would just have `SELECT SplitString("1,2,3,4,5,6,7", ",", 6)`

You can, of course, use `GenerateSQLSplit` to create the query (I made sure it returned an empty string if the item was not in the string, so you can use that to test if an nth element exists). I do not recommend it, though, because the query will be long, inefficient and hard to maintain.

Comment: I m afraid that i cant use a user-defined function due the fact that there are multiple databases with a problem that people inserted multiple values where only one was allowed. (mistake in a db template). Really looking for a SQL statement that other people can just copy and paste so the problem is fixed.

Comment: See my edit for how to do that, and why it's a bad plan

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You made It is really clear that it is a idea to do it with only SQL. It took me a while to understand what happend in your SQL statement and how it is created. Its to bad that a user defined function is not the best solution in my case due the fact that somebody with not much experience with access has to do it without my help. I m currently thinking about a solution where I run alternating queries until all the information has been transferred. But this is not at all a clean solution so I m still looking for something better.

Comment: Well, if you really want to do it in a union query, 3 splits isn't that long yet: `IIf( InStr(InStr(1,column_value,',') +1, column_value,',')> 0, IIf(InStr(InStr(InStr(1,column_value,',') +1, column_value,',') +1, column_value , ',') < 1, Mid(column_value, InStr(InStr(1,column_value,',') +1, column_value,',') +1), Mid(column_value, InStr(InStr(1,column_value,',') +1, column_value,',') +1, InStr(InStr(InStr(1,column_value,',') +1, column_value,',') +1, column_value , ',') - InStr(InStr(1,column_value,',') +1, column_value,',') -1)), "")` after replacing `Len(',')` with `1`.

Comment: Just found out that it is possible to have 10 splits so i have to find another way. But you have answerd my question so THANKS!