# Microsoft Access SQL Comma Delimited Values

Tags: sql, ms-access, split

I have a dataset with a primary key called authors and a field called books.

The table looks something like this:

```
Authors (primary key)     Books
John                      Fathom,Mouseover,Keycard
Kyle                      Teachers,Carl,Phone
```

I know this violates 1NF, and I'm attempting to create a new table (one to many relationship) with the primary key (authors) occurring more than once for each book. ie

```
Authors                   Books
John                      Fathom
John                      Mouseover
John                      Keycard
Kyle                      Teachers
Kyle                      Carl
Kyle                      Phone
```

I need to use SQL in microsoft access, and I think it involves the split function, but I'm at a loss for how to perform this query.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: over 1000, too many to do it manually i believe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Split column based on 1 or more possible delimiter and insert in new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014018/sql-split-column-based-on-1-or-more-possible-delimiter-and-insert-in-new-table) (as I said there, you either have to use VBA, or have to have a pretty limited amount of comma's (2 is doable, more is trouble))

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for your response, at most I have 2 commas in my data. I see your sql code you posted, but i'm unsure how to put it into SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the code is rather difficult to implement, and you only have 2, I guess I can share an implemented solution:

(replace `MyTable` with your tablename, and find and replace all field names with the correct one):

```
SELECT * Into NewTable FROM (
SELECT Author, IIf(InStr(1, [Books], ',') = -1, [Books], Left([Books], InStr(1, [Books], ',') - 1)) As Book
FROM MyTable
WHERE IIf(InStr(1, [Books], ',') = -1, [Books], Left([Books], InStr(1, [Books], ',') - 1)) <> ""
UNION ALL
SELECT Author, IIf( InStr(1,[Books],',')> 0, IIf(InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') < 1, Mid([Books], InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(',')), Mid([Books], InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') - InStr(1,[Books],',') - Len(','))), "")  As Book
FROM MyTable
WHERE IIf( InStr(1,[Books],',')> 0, IIf(InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') < 1, Mid([Books], InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(',')), Mid([Books], InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') - InStr(1,[Books],',') - Len(','))), "")  <> ""
UNION ALL
SELECT Author, IIf( InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',')> 0, IIf(InStr(InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') < 1, Mid([Books], InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(',')), Mid([Books], InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(','), InStr(InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') - InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') - Len(','))), "")  As Book
FROM MyTable
WHERE IIf( InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',')> 0, IIf(InStr(InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') < 1, Mid([Books], InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(',')), Mid([Books], InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(','), InStr(InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') + Len(','), [Books] , ',') - InStr(InStr(1,[Books],',') + Len(','), [Books],',') - Len(','))), "") <> ""
)
```