# SQL AlphaNumerical sort in Access with special characters

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access

I would like to create a sort in Access so the following sample data set is ordered in the following way.

The data set (correct order):

```
+---------+
|   ID    |
+---------+
| 1/1     |
| 2       |
| 2/GEN   |
| 2/1     |
| 2/2     |
| 3       |
| 5/1BR   |
| 99/1    |
| 100/2   |
| 501/2   |
| 999/3/2 |
+---------+
```

This is how Access sorts the data:

```
+---------+
|   ID    |
+---------+
| 1/1     |
| 100/2   |
| 2       |
| 2/1     |
| 2/2     |
| 2/GEN   |
| 3       |
| 5/1BR   |
| 501/2   |
| 99/1    |
| 999/3/2 |
+---------+
```

Essentially each slash is a subfile to the parent file (may also be a sub-file to the sub-file in the example of 999/3/2). The sort should sort numerically for the parent files (e.g 2 is the parent of 2/1), then for subfiles, it should be alphabetically (GEN has a higher priority than 2/1) followed by numerically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MS Access has very poor string operations, no support for JSON or XML, and not support for CTEs.  I think you will need to write your own functions to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the old trick:

```
Select * From YourTable
Order By Val([ID]), [ID]
```

Comment: That should certainly work, except for those more deeply nested files (the last row in the example)

Comment: You could use split () with @Gustav Val answer to handle the nesting? Depending on the number of levels, you might need a function.

Comment: @Minty For splitting, you get into trouble without a VBA solution. I've written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47014393/7296893) to illustrate that fact. You can go about 3 levels deep, and then you really need VBA or get horrible SQL strings.

Comment: @Erik - Good point and I'm not disagreeing. Just thought it might be a simple solution if the nesting was limited.